# What file uses .md extension and how should I edit them?

Tags: markdown, file-extension

On GitHub, several projects have `README.md` files. It seems like a simple format file to express text and pictures.

I guess there is an editor or syntax explanation somewhere.

Where can I find an introduction to `.md` files?

Comment: I guess this is evidence in favor of using the `.markdown` extension instead, though it's so awfully long...

Comment: Here is a link that may help you -> [.MD File Extension](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/md)

Comment: [MarkPad](http://code52.org/DownmarkerWPF/ "MarkPad") is a nice application for MarkDown editing in Windows. It presents you with the preview of the edits.

Comment: User can try [MarkView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markview/iaddkimmopgchbbnmfmdcophmlnghkim), a Chrome extension for editing and viewing markdown file inside the browser.

Comment: Xcode can be used to view/edit/read these files.

Comment: Full guide to help you start with `markdown`: http://blog.wax-o.com/2014/04/tutorial-short-guide-to-start-with-markdown/. You should try to write markdown with a way to live visualizing the result (with an application like http://mouapp.com/). Did you know that stackoverflow post and comment syntax is based on markdown ? :) http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 807, accepted):

Markdown is a plain-text file format. The extensions `.md` and `.markdown` are just text files written in [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) syntax. If you have a `Readme.md` in your repo, GitHub will show the contents on the home page of your repo. Read the documentation:

- [Standard Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)
- [GitHub Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/)

You can edit the `Readme.md` file in GitHub itself. Click on Readme.md, you will find an edit button. You can preview your changes and even commit them from there.

Since it is a text file, Notepad or Notepad++ (Windows), TextEdit (Mac) or any other text editor can be used to edit and modify it. Specialized editors exist that automatically parse the markdown as you type it and generate a preview, while others apply various syntax coloring and decorations to the displayed text. In both cases though, the saved file is still a readable text file.

If you want to create an `md` file with preview and if you prefer not to install any special editors, you can use online editors like [dillinger.io](https://dillinger.io) and [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io). They provide live preview. You can also export your files to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) or [Dropbox](https://dropbox.com).

Comment: I found Github's [basic explanation](https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics) very useful as a quick introduction too.

Comment: On Windows you might want to use WordPad to make use of the formatting for an easier read.

Comment: @GO'Rilla, IMHO avoid WordPad like the plague unless writing little notes to yourself that you will never share with anyone. What it adds to the .txt file can wreak havoc on other editors (vim, Notepad++, etc). Much better to work in plain text when dealing with .txt and use a word processor or Acrobat for non .txt textual files like .doc and .pdf.

Comment: can we add images or through link in .md file... is it possible?

Comment: @user1645290 Yes, it's possible. [see](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#images)

Comment: Under which scenarios should this format be used? I know you can use it if you have the intention of using the information in it in a web page. I had the intention of using it for a simple note, something not really important about the (Git) repo, but good to have at hand and to know, just in case. Should I use .md in a case like that?

Answer (score 93):

If you are looking for an editor, I suggest you use http://dillinger.io/. It is a simple browser-based text editor that can render Markdown on the fly.

However, if you prefer an app, and you are using OS X, you could try [Mou](http://mouapp.com/). It is quite good and full of examples.

Comment: It seems to be back to life?

Comment: I'd like suggest [http://dillinger.io/](http://dillinger.io/), another really cool browser-based text editor. It also allows you to link Dropbox, Github and Google drive.

Comment: The Notepad link in this answer triggers a RAR file download. Why is there no webpage, didn't you say it was a browser-based editor?

Comment: that link is no longer valid

Comment: Just pointing out that this is not a full answer to the question. You don't explain what .md is, only how it can be edited

Comment: @Zoe is right. Improve the answer. The information about the editor is a side note.

Answer (score 50):

Github's [Atom text editor](https://atom.io/) has a [live-preview mode](https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview) for markdown files.

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+M</kbd>.

> It can be activated from the editor using the <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+M</kbd> key-binding and is currently enabled for `.markdown`, `.md`, `.mkd`, `.mkdown`, and `.ron` files.

[image]

Answer (score 45):

Microsoft's [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) text editor has built in support for .md files written in markdown syntax.

The syntax is automatically color-coded inside of the .md file, and a preview window of the rendered markdown can be viewed by pressing `Shift+Ctrl+V` (Windows) or `Shift+Cmd+V` (Mac).

To see them side-by-side, drag the preview tab to the right side of the editor, or use `Ctrl+K V` (Windows) or `Cmd+K V` (Mac) instead.

[image]

VS Code uses the [marked library](https://github.com/chjj/marked) for parsing, and has [Github Flavored Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/#GitHub-flavored-markdown) support enabled by default, but it will not display the Github Emoji inline like Github's [Atom text editor](https://atom.io/) does.

Also, VS Code supports has several markdown plugins available for extended functionality.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2015 instead see my answer below.

Answer (score 17):

Extension '*.md*' refers to *Markdown* files.

If you don't want to install an app to read them in that format, 
you can simply use **TextEdit** or **Xcode** itself to open it on Mac.

On any other OS, you should be able to open it using **any text editor**, though as expected, you will not see it in *Markdown* format.

Comment: Actually, you _will_ see it in Markdown format. You won't see it as bold, italics, indents and code blocks, though.

Answer (score 14):

Yup, just [GitHub flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/). Including a README file in your repository will help others quickly determine what it's about and how to install it. Very helpful to include in your repos.

Comment: Downvoted. By “one” in “including one in your repository” you should mean “a README file in any format”, not just “a README.md file”. But the question is asking about “.md” files in general, not about READMEs in general. So this answer is irrelevant to the question. Also, the ambiguity with “one” could make a reader think that Markdown READMEs are necessarily better than other READMEs, which is wrong.

Comment: I made the change specified in the previous comment, because it makes sense and I think it could help avoid confusion.  I don't think this is a very good answer, though, as it adds nothing new that's relevant.  This question isn't about README's, it is about the .md extension.  There's no reason to add this answer six weeks after the accepted answer provided the same information.

Answer (score 5):

[Stack Edit](https://stackedit.io/) is an online markdown editor with the ability to save to Google Drive and DropBox.

Answer (score 5):

Markdown is just a text file which optionally has `.md`, or `.markdown` extensions. It can be converted to HTML. To know syntax of Markdown, Check out

[GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown).

You can use any text editor for markdown. If you are `sublime text` user, you can check out `Markdown Preview` plugin which will display the rendered markdown content in browser and updates whenever you change the markdown file.

Some of the online markdown editor

- [Markable](http://markable.in/editor/)
- [dillinger](http://dillinger.io/)
- [markdownviewer](http://www.markdownviewer.com/)

Answer (score 4):

[BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html) will also display MD on the mac.

and here is a [quicklook plugin](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown) to display them when you preview them.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io). It is simple WISIWIG editor. You can use both editor and markdown syntax. There is a quick markdown help syntax there. Undo/redo, comments, GoogleDrive, Dropbox interconnection.

Answer (score 2):

[markable.in](http://markable.in/editor/) is a very nice online tool for editing Markdown syntax

Answer (score 2):

There is an ongoing effort to standardize Markdown and as of now, this is probably the best place to learn about markdown:

http://standardmarkdown.com/

Comment: It's http://commonmark.org now (see http://blog.codinghorror.com/standard-markdown-is-now-common-markdown)

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating .md files for your .NET solutions I recommend the Visual Studio 2015 extension [Markdown Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaab33c3-437b-4918-8354-872dfe5d1bfe) as it has a preview panel so you can see your changes in real time.

**EDIT**: This also should now work with Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2):

A `.md` file stands for a Markdown file extension. A popular app for editing these files is [Typora](https://typora.io/)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do, if you do not have a reader, is to open the MD file with a text editor and then write the MD file out as an HTML file and then double click to view it with browser.

Comment: This will only work if you have a plugin that reads .md files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to chip in some money, [Writage](https://www.writage.com/) is pretty good.
It's a Microsoft Word add-on that enables Word to save in markdown format and read markdown files (.md or .markdown).

It doesn't work with all of Word's features, but it does enough to do most of what I need it to. It has its own tab in the ribbon so you can edit with the features it does support.

It's great because you can see the text the way it would be displayed while also being able to edit it in place.

https://www.writage.com/

The Writage ribbon tab:

NOTE: After installing, you have to restart Word in order for it to show up
[image]
A snippet of the intro page it gives you after installing:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The .md stands for Markdown Text. Basically, its just another type of text file, like .txt

I use Notepad++ for reading and editing these

Answer (score 0):

**Basic writing and formatting syntax to .md files **

You can see the official [documentation on Github](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax)