# Github - What does the markdown file do?

Tags: github, markdown

A `.md` file goes along with the source code files in the `github` zip. What does this file do and how should I use it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922882/whats-the-file-extension-md-how-should-i-edit-them

Comment: It's just a text file that is capable of formatting your text a certain way when seen online.  Think of it as a very dumbed down version of HTML.  In fact, you used mark down(.md) when you wrote this question.  http://whatismarkdown.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown is a kind of relative link.
Using markdown file you can link directly between different documentation files, whether you view the documentation on GitHub itself, or locally, using a different markup renderer.

So instead of an absolute link:

```
[a link](https://github.com/user/repo/blob/branch/other_file.md)
```

…you can use a relative link:

```
[a relative link](other_file.md)
```

and make sure it gets linked to user/repo/blob/branch/other_file.md.

Take a look: https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files