# What uses a .md~ file extension

Tags: file-extension

I found a `*.md~` in my gitignore and can't remember when/why I added it. Of course googling ["*.md~"](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=.md~+file+type) is useless (I know .md is used for markdown files, but the tilde is what I'm curious about). Is this a temp file Vim generates or something?

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What file uses .md extension and how should I edit them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922882/what-file-uses-md-extension-and-how-should-i-edit-them)

Answer (score 1):

`.md` file type stands for markdown. It's usually used for `README.md` on github.

See: [What file uses .md extension and how should I edit them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922882/what-file-uses-md-extension-and-how-should-i-edit-them)

Answer (score 1):

Files with the `~` (tilde) suffix are usually a backup of the previous file before your text editor saved a new version. Some text editors do this, and others don't. By default vim does.

You don't want to commit backup files into git (that's the reason for using source control!), which is why you have the `*.md~` in gitignore. Although I would suggest having something like `*~` to exclude all backup files if your text editor creates copies of files when saving.